# Can a kid profile battle another trainer in great league in Pokémon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know I can't add friends since I made the profile for my 6yo, but can I still battle another trainer in the Great League? If not, why are they giving us special research tasks we can't complete? Lol. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, child profiles are able to do PvP Battle Leagues. If your child's profile is currently unable to use these feature, then you can enable it accordingly through the various portal sites

> If your child logs into Pokémon GO using Niantic Kids or Pokémon Trainer Club (PTC), you can opt into enabling social features such as  Friends, Gifting, and Trading and Trainer Battles for your child in either the  [Niantic Kids Parent Portal](https://parents.nianticlabs.com/) or [Pokémon Trainer Club](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/login) website. You can also revoke your child’s access to these features at any time.
>
> <sub>[Niantic Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?l=en&p=all&s=friends-gifting-and-trading&f=how-can-my-child-access-social-features-such-as-friends-gifting-and-trading)</sub>